# Django Web App on Azure, does not pull remote sqlite3 database

Tags: django, azure, sqlite

I have a django web app up and running with Azure. Now, when there are changes in the remote database, I cannot pull it so that it is local (It doesn't detect any changes even though the sqlite3 file is included in the project and the commits). And if I try to sync or push, the remote database gets reset/overwritten with my local database. I cannot simply do the git ignore trick because I need to push the database after I created new models (I'm assuming the remote database does not have my local migrations) Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Here are my database settings in the settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'db.sqlite3'),
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
}
}
```

[image]

My git ignore file:

```
# Python cache
__pycache__/
*.pyc

# PTVS analysis
.ptvs/

# Build results
/bin/
/obj/

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Auto-generated virtual environment
/env/

# Auto-generated web.config
/web.config

# Auto-collected static files folder
/static/

# Windows image file caches
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db

# Folder config file
Desktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Mac desktop service store files
.DS_Store
```

Comment: could you include your project structure where the SQLite file is, and the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Are you sure that `db.sqlite3` is tracked in the commit? Does it show in the list of files git is tracking?

Comment: Yes, I tried changing something locally, and when I pushed up, the changes were applied at the server as well

Answer (score -1):

This is surely a very bad idea. Your remote database will surely be updated all the time, with live data created by the users of your website. Why would you want to override that with stale data from dev?

And this:

> I'm assuming the remote database does not have my local migrations

is not only false, it's quite literally missing the *whole point* of migrations, which is that you run the same code in dev and prod to keep the tables in sync.

Finally, sqlite isn't really suitable for production use in anything but a toy site. Use a proper db like Postgres.

Comment: Suppose that his web app works on _static_ data stored in a _sqlite_ database, which is certainly possible for use cases like displaying list of countries, where the data is small in size, and can be easily changed by replacing the file. SQLite can be used in production if the use case justifies it.

Comment: I still can't really see the use case here. If he has static data, it's best stored either in the file system, or updated in the real database via migrations.

Comment: I don't want to override the live data from dev. But I will have to push up my db from dev if I add new models or edit old models, dont I?

Comment: No, you can simply apply migrations on the production database if you want only to create the tables in database. The usual deployment pipeline is- update git repo, apply migrations, restart server. You need to do a ./manage.py migrate on the server database every time your models are updated

Comment: Is it possible to do this on azure? there seems to be no documentation on this

Comment: Possible to do *what*? Azure, if it's anything like Heroku, will run your migrations for you when you push.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know that web services run migrations automatically